# Align iframe in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have css like this

```
.iframe1 {
position: fixed; 
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 160px;
padding-right: 160px;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

This aligns center in all browsers except IE7. I know it's an old browser but my client insists on it. Instead of aligning center in IE7 it only pads 160px to the left and not center.

How do I center this in IE?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

text-align:center is usually the way to correct this issue in IE7.  If you get rid of the position:fixed, you should be good to go.  I don't see a need for the fixed position otherwise.

Comment: I changed it to `position: absolute` and it still doesn't change anything. I need position absolute or fixed for height: 100%

Comment: Does it work without the position tag?  If so, you might want to find an alternate way to get the 100% height.  You might want to try display:block.

Comment: what happens is if I remove padding-left + padding-right, the iframe is centered all right. The position doesn't really matter since position fixed works in IE7 in this case. However I need the padding or at least margin left and right since I have two absolutely placed sidebars on each side. My issue now is that I can't center the iframe in IE7 as long as I have the two paddings, the iframe is skewed to the right. The left padding 160px works, but the right padding 160px doesn't work at all...

Comment: Is it possible to remove the sidebars and fit everything into 3 cell type format?  Where as cell A is 160px cell B is open and cell C is 160 px.  I am not saying necessarily to use a table, but you might want to reconsider your format.
If not, you might need to use a container field much like the one I describe above.  You could leave a blank field essentially for the left and right container and add content into the middle.  That would not be ideal, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<center><div class="iframe1>bla bla</div></center>
```

or this:

Internet Explorer:

```
.iframe1 , * html .frame1 , *+html iframe1 {
margin: auto\9;
margin: auto\0/;
position: fixed; 
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 160px;
padding-right: 160px;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `<center>`, it's been marked deprecated in HTML 4.01, and that was in 1999...